# The inference file that goes into the entry point of PyTorchModel to be deployed does not have an effect to the output of the predictor

Tags: pytorch, prediction, amazon-sagemaker

I am currently running the code on AWS Sagemaker, trying to predict data using an already-trained model, accessed by MODEL_URL.

With the code below, the inference.py as the entry_point does not seem to have an effect on the result of the trained prediction model. Any changes in inference.py does not alter the output (the output is always correct). Is there something I am misunderstanding with how the model works? And how can I incorporate inference.py to the prediction model as the entry point?

```
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()

model = PyTorchModel(model_data = MODEL_URL, 
                            role = role,
                            framework_version = '0.4.0',
                            entry_point = '/inference.py',
                            source_dir = SOURCE_DIR)

predictor = model.deploy(instance_type = 'ml.c5.xlarge', 
                                   initial_instance_count = 1,
                                   endpoint_name = RT_ENDPOINT_NAME)

result = predictor.predict(someData)
```

Answer (score 0):

The entrypoint (`inference.py`) is the code file that defines how a model is loaded, input preprocessing, prediction logic, and output postprocessing.

> Any changes in inference.py does not alter the output

What are you changing in `inference.py` that you expect alter the `result` of `predictor.predict`? If the underlying `model_data` is not changing, the entry point script will be using the same model. Are you making some change to loading the model in `model_fn`, or in processing predictions via `input_fn`, `predict_fn`, or `output_fn`?